# AUI input keyup detection does't work

Tags: input, liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I have this script:

```
<aui:script use="aui-node,aui-io-request,aui-base,event">
AUI().use('event', 'aui-node', 'aui-base', function (A) {

    var inputObject = A.one('#_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost').on('keyup', function (event) {
        alert("Hi you have performed On change Event and Thank You");
    });
})
</aui:script>
```

Why doesn't the alert ever appear?

Comment: Try this`A.one('#_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost').delegate('keyup',function(event){
        alert("Hi you have performed On change Event and Thank You");
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues:

1. You do not need to specify an `AUI().use(//...` if you are using `<aui:script>` with the `use` attribute.
2. You only need to specify the `aui-node` module as an argument to the `use` attribute.
3. You most likely do not want to set `inputObject` equal to the return value of the [`on`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Node.html#method_on) method. Instead it seems that you would want to do `var inputObject = A.one('#id');`.
4. A `change` event is not the same as a `keyup` event, so either your `.on('change', function(event) { //...` or your `alert` message  which claims that it is an `onchange` event is incorrect.
5. You may have an issue with your `A.one('#_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost')` failing to find the element (check the browser logs to find out if this is true). If it is, your element may have a partially generated prefix which can be obtained using `<portlet:namespace />`.

If you put all that together:

```
<aui:script use="aui-node">
    // possibly change the A.one() argument to '#<portlet:namespace />_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost'.
    var inputObject = A.one('#_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost');
    inputObject.on('keyup', function (event) {
        alert("Hi you have performed On keyup Event and Thank You");
    });
</aui:script>
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
YUI().use('aui-node', function(A) {
    var inputObject = A.one('#_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost');
    inputObject.on('keyup', function (event) {
        alert("Hi you have performed On keyup Event and Thank You");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<input id="_Tend_ApplicationMain_WAR_ETenderportlet_vrednost" />
```